# dynamic allocation of bidimensional array

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-allocation

I have a function that dynamically creates a bisimentional array which memorizes a string of words read until "gata" is introduced.

The problem is that it crashes and I think the line

```
*(*words+*dim-1) = (char*)calloc(MAX_DIM,sizeof(char));
```

might be one of the problems.What is wrong with this line?

```
void read_words(char ***words,int *dim)
    {
      char buff[100];
      *words = (char**)calloc(*dim,*dim*sizeof(char*));
      while(strcmp(buff,"gata"))
       {
         printf("the new word : ");
         scanf("%100s", buff);
         if(strcmp(buff,"gata"))
          {
            dim++;
            *words = (char**)realloc(words,*dim*sizeof(char*));
            if(words == NULL)
             {
               printf("Memory allocation failed !\n");
               exit(0);
             }
            *(*words+*dim-1) = (char*)calloc(MAX_DIM,sizeof(char));
            strcpy(*(*words+*dim-1),buff);
          }
       }
    }

int main()
{
  char **words;
  int i,dim = 0;

  read_words(&words,&dim);

  for (i = 0; i < dim; i++)
    free(&words[i]);
  free(words);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: is **new** present in c?

Comment: @Fennekin was there a nija edit? I don't see `new`.

Comment: `dim++`, where dim is int*...

Comment: reminder: this is c, add stars until it compiles

Comment: well I don't know whether new operator is in 'c' or not. but If it is present, then the work will become a lot easier

Answer (score 1):

The primary problem is with

```
  while(strcmp(buff,"gata"))
```

where `buff` is an automatic local variable and left uninitialized. Using the contents invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You need to initialize `buff` before using it.

That said,

- `scanf("%100s", buff);` opens up the possibility of going [off-by-one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error), make that `scanf("%99s", buff);`.
- `dim++;` increments the pointer itself, not the value pointed to by the pointer.

Comment: That's not the problem . The dynamic allocation is,and i don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @NickName : once the pointer is incremented, its value is undefined or meaningless. It can explain a crash as dim is dereferenced `*dim` when the allocation is performed.

Comment: @francis Thanks for the effort, but as I see from the previous comment from OP it's unlikely to make any effect on _OP_, looks like any other suggestion is not going to be accepted. :)

Comment: even if i change it with (*dim)++ it still crashes before the line *(*words+*dim-1) = (char*)calloc(MAX_DIM,sizeof(char));